# Can Jersey's ServletContainer init method be overridden?

Tags: java, maven, jersey, initialization, servlet-container

Writing a Web Service in Java (Jersey/Maven). I'd like to construct a class that builds a number of databases before the application is deployed - as all of its resources depend on those databases. Although there is a textual representation of the Jersey's `ServletContainer` source code, it has already been compiled into bytecode and packed into a jar and, thus, cannot be edited. Is the solution as simple as declaring an instance of the `ServletContainer` class in my code and overriding the init method there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do all your initialization in the [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html).

```
package org.foo;

public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        // initialize here
        packages("the.packages.to.scan");
    }
}
```

And you can declare it in the web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>org.foo.AppConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

For other deployment options see [Servlet-based Deployment](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet)

Comment: Getting an error now saying that a suitable constructor for AppConfig cannot be found. The class I am trying to initialize at deployment is not an annotated resource. It simply builds the databases that the resources use. Is this part of the problem?

Comment: That error doesn't make any sense if you're doing it right. With what I have above, you would not get this error. And I didn't say anything about annotated resources. For better help, I'd need to see a lot more. At least enough to where I can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have no doubt I'm doing it wrong, thus the error. My guess is that the trouble is occurring in the initialization section of the AppConfig constructor. I call `registerClasses(DbBuilder.class)` and then I instantiate a new instance of the DbBuilder class before calling `packages("package.that.contains.DbBuilder")`.

Comment: Why do you register the `DbBuilder`. And do you know what `packages` does? It tells Jersey to scan the package for `@Path` resources and `@Provider` providers. Same as using the initparam in the web.xml to can the package. How were you plainning on initializing the db if you could override the `init` method in the `ServletContainer`. So the same thing here. Why do you need to register anything? If you're trying to use DI, that's a different story, and probably requires a different question, but I don't think that is the case